# What is a finite verb?

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs

What's a *finite verb*? It's not just the opposite of an infinitive, is it? Can I get some examples?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thinking of a *finite* verb as the opposite of an infinitive isn't a bad way to start, actually.

The core definition of a *finite* verb is one that is inflected for person and tense. Typically only finite verbs can act as the main verb of a sentence. In the following examples, the *italicized* verbs are finite:

> I *wanted* **to go** to the store.
>
> The girls *were* **talking** to each other loudly.
>
> A child *has* **gone** missing.

However, the **bolded** segments above, while part of the verb phrase, are *non-finite* verbs. The first is an infinitive, the second is a present participle, and the third is a past participle, these being the primary forms of non-finite verbs in English. If you remove the finite verb from all of the sentences above you no longer have a complete sentence.

Comment: Answer:A1 Definitions:A1 Examples:A1

Comment: Another quick definition could be a verb that normally requires a subject and agrees with it in number.

Comment: As a bit of a special case, verbs used in imperatives are considered finite, even though they doesn't inflect for person or tense, require a subject, or agree with it in number.

Comment: @Jason, imperatives in most languages do, in fact, agree in number and often indicate tense. English is something of a special case, since our imperatives take a zero marker for number and do not include a past (or future) imperative.