# Why do some people say "there have voted"? Is it grammatical, or maybe historical?

Tags: grammaticality

In a certain debating chamber, it is routinely stated ("content" means a yes vote):

> There have voted — [such-and-such]: content; [such-and-such]: not content."

I'm not sure that this is grammatically correct. I think you can only have "been" or "not been" after "there have" at the start of a sentence. Could someone educate me as to why this is grammatical, or if it isn't, why they choose to repeatedly use an ungrammatical construction?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the formatting to make it easier to parse. Please double-check that it still means what you intended. :)

Comment: Seems to be the standard phrasing for official votes in the House of Lords: http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld/ldcomp/compso2010/ldctso10.htm

Answer (score 6):

This is in fact a legitimate construction, though formal and old fashioned, and limited by certain conditions not all of which I am fully aware of. Consider this quote from the standard modernised rendering of the [Declaration of Arbroath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_of_Arbroath), the famous declaration of independence of the Scots in 1320:

> In their kingdom there have reigned
> one hundred and thirteen kings of
> their own royal stock, the line
> unbroken by a single foreigner.

This construction is a case of **balance inversion**, where putting the subject in first position would result in a very late position of the [finite verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/what-is-a-finite-verb), which is often considered uncomely and ponderous:

> *In their kingdom, one hundred and thirteen kings of their own royal
> stock, the line unbroken by a single
> foreigner, have reigned.

I agree that the "there have reigned" construction is rare and out of place in informal language, and unnecessarily pompous in short sentences. It is probably a matter of tradition in your case, since this exact formula is standard in the House of Lords, as Nico has mentioned.

Comment: +1; "In their kingdom there have reigned" was the example I was trying to think of. There is a slight difference in this sentence in that it opens with "In their kingdom..." In my opinion, that makes this construction much easier on the ear. Also of note: _have_ is not the only option. "In this meal there were eaten many steaks."

Comment: Ah, excellent, I don't have to go do the work of hunting for this now :-)

Comment: @MrHen: While an adverbial constituent in first position is common with this construction, I don't believe it is required; cf. this quote: http://books.google.com/books?id=wWtIAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA518&lpg=PA518&dq=%22there+have+reigned%22+-%22in+their+kingdom%22&source=bl&ots=pQ19OkmXuB&sig=ZYhjmFmNMnoGpcH35IUJT6DwbJU&hl=en&ei=kpuoTa-KNsWSOvDI1OAJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22there%20have%20reigned%22%20-%22in%20their%20kingdom%22&f=false I think it is rather the length of the subject and its attributes that matters: all that normally has to come first.

Comment: Maybe I'm completely wrong, but isn't it the same type of construction as, for instance, *There should be ....*?

Comment: @nico: Yes, but I think this particular question is about the present perfect used in the active voice...

Comment: @Cerberus: it just looks to me that you can rephrase it as *There have been these votes:* or *The Lords have voted as such:*. I would just read the *there* as an "indefinite" term (possibly substituting the subject?)

Comment: @nico: Yes, you could rephrase it in both ways you mentioned, and yes I agree "there" is a kind of impersonal dummy pre-subject. But I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to say. The OP just wanted to know whether this particular construction was correct.

Comment: @Cerberus: oh, just wanted to say that is not an *extremely* bizarre construction, that's all :)

Comment: @nico: Haha, that sounds my all means reasonable!